# Musixtex: annotate an score with arrow and text

Tags: musixtex

It´s needed to annotate an score using arrow and text, the code is as follow:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
%Rutinas para Musixtex
\newcommand{\BBBl}[5][0]%
{\ibbbl{#1}{#2}{#3}\qb{#1}{#4}\tqb{#1}{#5}}
\newcommand{\BBBBl}[5][0]%
{\ibbbbl{#1}{#2}{#3}\qb{#1}{#4}\tqb{#1}{#5}}

\begin{document}
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw [red,-{Stealth}] (0,0)--(0.5,-1);
%\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
%\draw (0,0) node {
%\node (image) at (0,0) {
%\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
%\tikz{\node[scale=1]{
\begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract
        %\startpiece
        \notes \wh j \sk \en
        %\Endpiece
        \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
        \startextract
        %\startpiece %\alaligne\alapage
        \notes \hl{j} \sk \hl{j} \sk \en%\alaligne
        %\Endpiece
        \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
        \startextract
        %\startpiece
        \notes \ql{j} \ql{j} \ql{j} \ql{j} \sk \en %\alaligne
        %\Endpiece
        \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
        \startextract
        %\startpiece
        \notes \Dqbl jj \Dqbl jj \Dqbl jj \Dqbl jj \en
        %\Endpiece
        \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
        \startextract
        %\startpiece
        \notes \Qqbbl jjjj \Qqbbl jjjj \Qqbbl jjjj \Qqbbl jjjj \en
        %\Endpiece
        \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
        \startextract
        %\startpiece
        \notes \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \en
        %\Endpiece
        \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
\end{music}
%};}
\end{center}
%\end{figure}
 %\end{tikzpicture}
        
\begin{center}
\tikz{\node[scale=0.7]{
        \begin{music}
        \smallmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startextract
        %\startpiece
        \notes \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j}\en
        %\Endpiece
        \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
        \end{music}    
        };}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output should be as follow:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Does it have to be in musixtex? This looks like a job for tikz. I think, there is some package, which is able to draw note heads. Otherwise, Inkscape is a good tool. You create a graphic in Inkscape, save as pdf and import with includegraphics.

Comment: Another solution is to use a savebox and use vspace{-\saveboxheight} and paint on top of the notes. I just see, that you have some tikz and musixtex stuff there. Excuse me, I'm on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `\startextract` and `\zendextract` but rather `\startpiece` and `\zendpiece` to typeset the music, because this will automatically fill a line. You can then easily set the line width using the `text width` option of the Ti*k*Z node.

You can use the `\scale{}` macro to set the right relative distances between the different music parts. Somehow the distance of the two half notes needed some additional manual adjustment. To manually add some horizontal spacing between the notes, you can use the `\off{}` macro.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
%Rutinas para Musixtex
\newcommand{\BBBl}[5][0]{%
    \ibbbl{#1}{#2}{#3}\qb{#1}{#4}\tqb{#1}{#5}%
}
\newcommand{\BBBBl}[5][0]{%
    \ibbbbl{#1}{#2}{#3}\qb{#1}{#4}\tqb{#1}{#5}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        scale=0.67, 
        transform shape,
        score/.style={
            anchor=west,
            align=left, 
            text width=21.25cm,
            inner sep=0pt
        },
        label/.style={
            anchor=east,
            align=center,
            text width=7em
        },
        every path/.style={
            draw=red, 
            very thick,
            line cap=round
        }
    ]
    %Primera partitura 
    \node[score] (A) at (0,0) {
    \begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece
        \scale{48}
        \notes 
            \off{0.5em}
            \wh j 
            \en
        \zendpiece %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Segunda partitura 
    \node[score] (B) at (0,-1.5) {
    \begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece
        \scale{24}
        \notes 
            \off{0.5em}
            \hl{j} 
            \off{0.25em}
            \hl{j} 
            \en
        \zendpiece %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Tercera partitura 
    \node[score] (C) at (0,-3) {
    \begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece
        \scale{12}
        \notes 
            \off{0.5em}
            \ql{j} 
            \ql{j}  
            \ql{j}  
            \ql{j} 
            \en
        \zendpiece %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Cuarta partitura 
    \node[score] (D) at (0,-4.5) {
    \begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece
        \scale{6}
        \notes 
            \off{0.5em}
            \Dqbl jj 
            \Dqbl jj 
            \Dqbl jj 
            \Dqbl jj 
            \en
        \zendpiece %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Quinta partitura 
    \node[score] (E) at (0,-6) {
    \begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece
        \scale{3}
        \notes 
            \off{0.5em}
            \Qqbbl jjjj 
            \Qqbbl jjjj 
            \Qqbbl jjjj 
            \Qqbbl jjjj 
            \en
        \zendpiece %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Sexta partitura 
    \node[score] (F) at (0,-7.5) {
    \begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece
        \scale{1.5}
        \notes 
            \off{0.5em}
            \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} 
            \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} 
            \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} 
            \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} 
            \en
        \zendpiece %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Septima partitura 
    \node[score] (G) at (0,-9) {
    \begin{music}
        \normalmusicsize
        \setclefsymbol1\empty
        \nobarnumbers
        \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
        \startpiece
        \scale{0.75}
        \notes 
            \off{0.5em}
            \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} 
            \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} 
            \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} 
            \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j}
            \en
        \zendpiece %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Lineas de redonda a blanca
    \draw 
        (0.6,-0.15) -- ++(0,-1)
        (0.8,-0.15) -- ++(10,-1);
    \draw 
        (0.6,-2) -- ++(0,-0.65)
        (0.8,-2) -- ++(5,-0.65)
        (10.95,-2) -- ++(0,-0.65)
        (11.15,-2) -- ++(5,-0.65);
    \draw 
        (0.6,-3.5) -- ++(0,-0.65)
        (0.8,-3.5) -- ++(2.33,-0.65)
        (5.8,-3.5) -- ++(0,-0.65)
        (6,-3.5) -- ++(2.33,-0.65);
    \draw 
        (0.6,-5.15) -- ++(0,-0.5)
        (0.8,-5.15) -- ++(1,-0.5)
        (3.2,-5.15) -- ++(0,-0.5)
        (3.4,-5.15) -- ++(1,-0.5);
    \draw 
        (0.6,-6.75) -- ++(0,-0.4)
        (0.8,-6.75) -- ++(0.5,-0.4)
        (1.85,-6.75) -- ++(0,-0.4)
        (2.05,-6.75) -- ++(0.5,-0.4)
        (3.1,-6.75) -- ++(0,-0.4)
        (3.3,-6.75) -- ++(0.5,-0.4)
        (4.35,-6.75) -- ++(0,-0.4)
        (4.55,-6.75) -- ++(0.5,-0.4);
    \draw 
        (0.6,-8.25) -- ++(0,-0.4)
        (0.8,-8.25) -- ++(0.1,-0.4)
        (1.2,-8.25) -- ++(0,-0.4)
        (1.4,-8.25) -- ++(0.1,-0.4);
    % annotations
    \node[label] at (A.west) {La redonda \\ vale};
    \node[label] at (B.west) {2 blancas \\ o};
    \node[label] at (C.west) {4 negras \\ o};
    \node[label] at (D.west) {8 corcheas \\ o};
    \node[label] at (E.west) {16 semicorcheas \\ o};
    \node[label] at (F.west) {32 fusas \\ o};
    \node[label] at (G.west) {64 semifusas};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

now the arrows works fine, only the width of the staff is not working... some suggestion in Musixtex code?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
%Rutinas para Musixtex
\newcommand{\BBBl}[5][0]%
{\ibbbl{#1}{#2}{#3}\qb{#1}{#4}\tqb{#1}{#5}}
\newcommand{\BBBBl}[5][0]%
{\ibbbbl{#1}{#2}{#3}\qb{#1}{#4}\tqb{#1}{#5}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    %Primera partitura 
    \node[text width=12cm,align=center, scale=0.9] at (6,0){
    \begin{music}
      \normalmusicsize
      \setclefsymbol1\empty
      \nobarnumbers
      \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
      \startextract
      \notes \sk \wh j \sk \en
      \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Segunda partitura 
    \node[text width=12cm,align=center, scale=0.9] at (6,-1.5){
    \begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \setclefsymbol1\empty
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract
    \notes \sk \hl{j} \sk \hl{j} \sk \en%\alaligne
    \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Tercera partitura 
    \node[text width=12cm,align=center, scale=0.9] at (6,-3){
    \begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \setclefsymbol1\empty
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract
    \notes \ql{j} \ql{j} \ql{j} \ql{j} \sk \en
    \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Cuarta partitura 
    \node[text width=12cm,align=center, scale=0.9] at (6,-4.5){
    \begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \setclefsymbol1\empty
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract
    \notes \Dqbl jj \Dqbl jj \Dqbl jj \Dqbl jj \en
    \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Quinta partitura 
    \node[text width=12cm,align=center, scale=0.9] at (6,-6){
    \begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \setclefsymbol1\empty
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract
    \notes \Qqbbl jjjj \Qqbbl jjjj \Qqbbl jjjj \Qqbbl jjjj \en
    \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Sexta partitura 
    \node[text width=12cm,align=center, scale=0.9] at (6,-7.5){
    \begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \setclefsymbol1\empty
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract
    \notes \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \BBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjj}{j} \en
    \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Septima partitura 
    \node[text width=12cm,align=center, scale=0.7] at (6,-9){
    \begin{music}
    \normalmusicsize
    \setclefsymbol1\empty
    \nobarnumbers
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract
    \notes \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j} \BBBBl{l}{0}{jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj}{j}\en
    \zendextract %Cierra de partitura sin barra vertical
    \end{music}};
    %Lineas de redonda a blanca
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (6,-0.15)--(5.55,-1.25);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (6.1,-0.15)--(6.45,-1.25);
    %Lineas de blanca a negra (par de izquierda)
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (5.45,-2.05)--(5.05,-2.8);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (5.55,-2.05)--(5.55,-2.8);
    %Lineas de blanca a negra (par de derecha)
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (6.35,-2.05)--(6.05,-2.8);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (6.45,-2.05)--(6.55,-2.8);
    %Lineas de negra a corchea
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (4.85,-3.55)--(4.45,-4.3);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (4.95,-3.55)--(4.85,-4.3);
    
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (5.45,-3.55)--(5.35,-4.3);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (5.50,-3.55)--(5.75,-4.3);
    
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (5.95,-3.55)--(6.25,-4.3);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (6.0,-3.55)--(6.60,-4.3);
    
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (6.5,-3.55)--(7.1,-4.3);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=3pt] (6.63,-3.55)--(7.5,-4.3);
    %Lineas de corchea a semi corchea
    \draw[draw=red, line width=2pt] (4.40,-5.0)--(3.0,-5.8);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=2pt] (4.40,-5.0)--(3.5,-5.8);
    %Lineas de semi corchea a fusa
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt] (2.9,-6.67)--(-0.1,-7.3);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt] (2.9,-6.67)--(0.3,-7.3);
    %Lineas de fusa a semi fusa
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt] (-0.15,-8.1)--(-3.4,-8.85);
    \draw[draw=red, line width=1pt] (-0.15,-8.1)--(-3.1,-8.85);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    



\end{document}
```

[image: The staff of the score is wrong: width should be adjusted]

The staff of the score is wrong: width should be adjusted

Comment: Fine. Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: Does this answer your question completely? If you still have questions you should ask them in the question part or in a new question.